# AngularJS ng-bind-html removes all script tag

Tags: angularjs

I am really new to AngularJS. So this question might be very basic but I don't get a clear answer from other post so I try to ask a new question.

I am woundering why angulars js *ng-bind-html* removes all **script** tags from the content I want to paste in my website.

I just try it with this code example from AngularJS documentation website which shows a simple bind-html example with a java script tag inside.

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('bindHtml', ['ngSanitize'])
        .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.myHTML =
                'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
                '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>'+
                '<script type="javascript">' +
                'alert(1);'+
                '</script>';

        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

This code snippet shows the html template:

```
<body ng-app="bindHtml">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

But the Chrome Inspector shows that AngularJS apparently removed all java script without a warning message. Exist a way to bypass this removing or do I have to rewrite all old style jquery and what ever javascript into AngularJS?
[Screenshot from code inspector of Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAlyT.png)

Thank you

Comment: try this $sce.trustAsHtml( $scope.myHTML).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your use case for injecting inline scripts from javascript into a template? Why not run your code in your application logic inside JavaScript?

Comment: Yes therefor exist not a good question. This project is still a bricolage of different frameworks and now Angular JS, too.... But thank you $sce.trustAsHtml is the right trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject $sce service into your controller or Directive etc. and use $sce service like this :-

```
$scope.myHTML= $sce.trustAsHtml("I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
                '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>'+
                '<script type="javascript">' +
                'alert(1);'+
                '</script>");
```

And bind this in your HTML page e.g;

```
<body ng-app="bindHtml">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. It dont removes the script tag now but java script wont be execute. Mmh, I test a bit but you will get a checkmark.

Comment: Thank you. It work. If someone have the same question, than please do not use my example with this simple alert because it wont work because it is missing a "document ready function". You may use something like _<i onmouseout="alert(1);">Go in and out</i>_

Comment: Document.ready is Jquery feature. try $sce.trustAsJs("<script type='javascript'>alert(1);</script>"). It will work.